# position is not working when the containing element is inside table - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

When my containing element(div) is inside `<td>`, and If i use `position()`, It is not returning the position relative to td. instead it returns position relative to `<tr>`.

Why this is happening? Any workaround for this?

Comment: Can we see the code? Thx

Answer (score 1):

`position()` returns the offset difference between the current element, and the closest *offset parent*.

If you want to get the position relative to the direct parent, use:

```
var element = $("div"); //Selector
var offset = element.offset().top - element.parent().offset().top;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `position` CSS property of the `<td>` to relative:
In your css file:

```
table td { position:relative; }
```